# Data.table: rbind a list of data tables with unequal columns

Tags: r

I have a list of data tables that are of unequal lengths. Some of the data tables have 35 columns and others have 36.

I have this line of code, but it generates an error

```
> lst <- unlist(full_data.lst, recursive = FALSE)
> model_dat <- do.call("rbind", lst)
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Item 1362 has 35 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 36 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fill' to TRUE.
```

Any suggestions on how I can modify that so that it works properly.

Comment: Error says that the objects you are trying to bind don't have equal number of columns.

Comment: As stated in the question, "Some of the data tables have 35 columns and others have 36."

Answer (score 5):

Here's a minimal example of what you are trying to do. 
No need to use any other package to do this. Just set `fill=TRUE` in `rbindlist`.

You can do this:

```
df1 <- data.table(m1 = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.table(m1 = c(1,2,3), m2=c(3,4,5))

df3 <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=T)

print(df3)

   m1 m2
1:  1 NA
2:  2 NA
3:  3 NA
4:  1  3
5:  2  4
6:  3  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `rbind.fill` from package `plyr`:

Input data, 3 dataframes with different number of columns

```
df1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),b=c(1,2,3,4,5))
df2<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df3<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),d=c(1,2,3))

full_data.lst<-list(df1,df2,df3)
```

The solution

```
library("plyr")
rbind.fill(full_data.lst)
   a  b  c  d
1  1  1 NA NA
2  2  2 NA NA
3  3  3 NA NA
4  4  4 NA NA
5  5  5 NA NA
6  1  1  1 NA
7  2  2  2 NA
8  3  3  3 NA
9  4  4  4 NA
10 5  5  5 NA
11 6  6  6 NA
12 1 NA NA  1
13 2 NA NA  2
14 3 NA NA  3
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, I could possibly see only two options for having your data tables appended.

Option A: Drop the extra variable from one of the datasets

```
table$column_Name <- NULL
```

Option B) Create the variable with missing values in the incomplete dataset.

```
full_data.lst$column_Name <- NA
```

And then do rbind function.